# Computing the limit of a function with undefined parts.

Tags: limits, functions, continuity

I'm having some trouble intuitively understanding the following limit calculation:

$$
\lim_{x\to 0} x^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = 0
$$

$x^2$ obviously goes to $0$ when $x$ approaches zero but $\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ is undefined for x approaching zero. Is $x^2$ dominant in this case? what about the general case where you have a composition of differentiable and continuous functions where the limit of one of them is undefined. How do you approach that problem?

Thank you for your help in advance

Comment: $\left|\sin \frac{1}{x} \right| \leq 1$ and hence $x^2 \left|\sin \frac{1}{x} \right| \leq x^2$. It is now clear that the limit is 0.

Comment: @Muralidharan Oh shoot, I hadn't seen your comment. I added this as an answer about 27 seconds later.

Comment: This one can be done by squeeze theorem. The other category (composition of functions) needs to be addressed more carefully. Can you give an example of the same?

Answer (score 3):

Note that $ |\sin x| \le 1$. So we have $$  \bigg{|}x^2 \sin \frac{1}{x}\bigg{|} \le x^2$$
So $$0\le\lim_{x \to 0} \bigg{|}x^2 \sin \frac{1}{x}\bigg{|}\le \lim_{x \to 0} x^2=0 \implies \lim_{x \to 0}  x^2 \sin \frac{1}{x}=0$$

$x^2$ effects the limit more because the $\sin$ function is bounded between $-1$ and $1$.

Comment: Thank you. this pretty much explains it :)

Comment: @user3047143 You're Welcome.